# How to fetch a column from csv A with a column as a key from csv B

Tags: command-line, csvkit

I am trying to correct my `districtname` column in `A.csv` by comapring it to National CSV database `B.csv`

Here are the contents of my `A.csv`

```
"Series","No","districtname","PinCode"
"A","101","Mysuru","570010"
"A","103","D. K. ","574216"
"A","104","Bengaluru","560004"
"A","105","Bengaluru","560010"
"A","106","Doddaballapura","561203"
"A","107","Bengaluru","560002"
"A","109","Bengaluru","560050"
"A","110","Bengaluru","560076"
"A","111","Tumkur ","572112"
```

Contents of `B.csv`

```
PinCode,districtname
744112,South Andaman
744101,South Andaman
744103,South Andaman
744104,South Andaman
744201,North And Middle Andaman
744107,South Andaman
744302,Nicobar
744301,Nicobar
744202,North And Middle Andaman
...……
```

How to use column `PinCode` in `A.csv` as a key to find out official District names mentioned in `B.csv`

A `csvkit` commandline method will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it's

```
csvjoin -I --left -c 4,1 fil1.csv file2.csv
```